# Observable.zip but get first value, don't wait for all values

Tags: observable, rxjs5, angular2-observables

Say I have this:

```
const a = new BehaviorSubject(0);
const b = new BehaviorSubject(0);

Observable.zip(
    a.asObservable(),
    b.asObservable()
)
.subscribe(v => {
    // this will fire with [0,0]
    // but I want it to also fire with [1,0]
});

a.next(1);
```

how can I achieve what's in the comment in the subscribe next function?
I believe I need to find a different operator than `Observable.zip()`, something like `Observable.first()`.

Comment: how about `.combineLatest()`?

Comment: idk, would it work?

Comment: add an answer, I will upvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.zip()` will only work if the emissions from the `observables` are zippable. For your case, because `0,0` is already zipped, hence there will only be one such emission. If you want to have next emission, your `b` subject will have to emit a value too:

```
const a = new BehaviorSubject(0);
const b = new BehaviorSubject(0);

Observable.zip(
    a.asObservable(),
    b.asObservable()
)
    .subscribe(v => {
        // this will fire with [0,0]
        // will fire only if both a and b has emisions. 
        // this also logs [1,1] because there is a b.next(1)
    });

a.next(1);
b.next(1); // this step is crucial
```

If you want to detect any changes of any number of `Observables` combined, you will have to use [`Observable.combineLatest()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html).

> The CombineLatest operator behaves in a similar way to Zip, but while Zip emits items only when each of the zipped source Observables have emitted a previously unzipped item, CombineLatest emits an item whenever any of the source Observables emits an item (so long as each of the source Observables has emitted at least one item). When any of the source Observables emits an item, CombineLatest combines the most recently emitted items from each of the other source Observables, using a function you provide, and emits the return value from that function.

Comment: thanks, do you know if I can use a projection function instead of wrapping it in Observable.create()?

Comment: @AlexanderMills edited my answer. As for projection function, not sure how you gonna do it, but usually if you just want to transform the data, `.map()` or `.switchMap()`  operator is good enough, it really depends on your use case though.

Comment: sorry, @CozyAzure, I got confused between this question, and this other question I asked today, check this one out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48635666/compare-most-recent-values-from-multiple-behaviorsubjects